# Laravel 9 - Jetstream with Bootstrap (Jetstrap). Missing app.css and shows ugly view

Tags: laravel, lamp, laravel-9, laravel-jetstream, jetstrap

I'm following this video tutorial (in spanish), which shows how to implement Jetstream with Bootstrap instead of Tailwinds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt-OuBX6lEc&list=PLZ2ovOgdI-kWWS9aq8mfUDkJRfYib-SvF&index=31

The issue is this one: despite I've followed the steps strictly, I'm getting two important errors.

First of all, I should have a file named "app.css" into my folder "/public/css", but I don't. I don't have even a folder named 'css' into the 'public' directory, neither another lots of folders I should.

On the other hand, both my welcome view and my register view look ugly, like this:

[image]

[image]

The commands I've done are these ones:

---

Into:
leandro@leandro-Lenovo-B50-10:/var/www/html$

laravel new bootstrap --jet

cd bootstrap

---

Then,into:
leandro@leandro-Lenovo-B50-10:/var/www/html/bootstrap$

composer require nascent-africa/jetstrap --dev

php artisan jetstrap:swap livewire

npm install

npm run dev

php artisan migrate

sudo chmod  -R 777 .

---

Also, the register view shows an error, unless I have activated VITE (with npm run dev).
Somewhere, I had to do a 'php artisan migrate:fresh', because a migration error.

I'm running the project into an Apache server.

I'm using:

- Linux Mint 21 Vanessa
- Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 8.2.1
- Laravel v9.50.2

Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong? It might be a conflict version, since I'm using Laravel 9, while the video is explained for Laravel 8.

I don't know if there's any additional information needed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that nascent-africa/jetstrap is designed for Laravel 8, and you're on Laravel 9 - and 10 is now the new release.

I don't have an answer for how to get bootstrap working in 9 or 10, though, that's how I found this question :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use Tailwind instead, since the support for Bootstrap it's not very good on Jetstream, and relies on third-party packages like Jetstrap, which support is not always optimum

Answer (score 1):

In case you are having hard time setting up  Laravel with [jetstrap](https://github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap), you can try this repo that I have created by using jetstrap package. It is using [Laravel 10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x) with [Boostrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), [jetsream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/3.x/introduction.html) Authentication. It also uses [vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#main-content) for Asset Bundling .

Basically, I used jetstrap with Laravel 9 to migrate everything from Tailwind to Boostrap then I have upgraded Laravel to version 10.

[This is a link to repo.](https://github.com/IAmShafqatAli/boostrap5-inertia-ssr)